# Is it possible to limit the permissions for a google sheet launched from the template gallery?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to know if it is possible to limit user access to certain tabs in a google sheet launched from the template gallery?

In our company, we have a sales department that uses an calculator builded on google sheet. In order to ensure that sellers always use the current version of the calculator (this is important because the parameters of the products change over time), I have placed its in google sheets template gallery and update it on a regular basis.

The problem is that one of the tabs in the sheet should not be available to sellers because it contains information about the prices of semi-finished products and materials, therefore there is a risk of their interference in these data and offering customers at lower prices (the product is very specific and prices are important even in scale 0.01 USD).

As you know, opening a new sheet from the template gallery makes the opener the owner of the file and thus he gets a full permissions to it. Therefore, setting sheet protection in the source file doesn't fix the problem.

Is there any solution how to handle with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do customers write in this tab?

Comment: Clients do not use this file at all. It is an internal worksheet for the sales department. In the 1st tab, the seller enters the input data and receives the result. The second tab, on the other hand, is the technical tab where all calculations are performed and here sellers should not have access at all - this is the one I want to block.

Comment: Hard to explain solution in words. Make for me 2 test sheets and put links here. One like your calculator. They must both be public. Then I can show you.

Comment: @Swen
Calculator file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMYPA0W0gPS1A4hIo8_hWNcdhE7jQdyAKpv37Wk3m1I/edit?usp=sharing
Second empty file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13vqFa2duep9Spc5AOEIvBUwdLr45VQOGy9EVwECiVEI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Solution is ready. Read my answer.

Comment: Thank you @iansedano Did you try  the solution Tomekk? You took it and disappeared. Not very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You use 2 sheets

Rename your "Test - Calculator" to **Calculator file** (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMYPA0W0gPS1A4hIo8_hWNcdhE7jQdyAKpv37Wk3m1I/edit?usp=sharing)
Permissions: **Private** (no sharing)

and rename "file 2" to **Client input file** (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13vqFa2duep9Spc5AOEIvBUwdLr45VQOGy9EVwECiVEI/edit?usp=sharing)
Permissions: **Public on the web** (Any1 with the link can edit)

You first connect these files together because you will use [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en-GB)

For file **Calculator file**
You must have 2 tabs (the more tabs do whatever you want, keep, delete makes no difference)

**Tab 1**: `solution for client`
In 1st tab you have this formula only, in cell **A1**
`=INDEX('aw7e%^y24@d9 strange tab name client can not guess'!A1:D22)`

**REMEMBER: ONLY from tab `solution for client` the client will see**

**Tab 2**: `aw7e%^y24@d9 strange tab name client can not guess`
This tab only for calculations
cell **C5**: `=IMPORTRANGE("13vqFa2duep9Spc5AOEIvBUwdLr45VQOGy9EVwECiVEI";"clientDATA!C3")`
cell **C6**: `=IMPORTRANGE("13vqFa2duep9Spc5AOEIvBUwdLr45VQOGy9EVwECiVEI";"clientDATA!C4")`
cell **C8**: `=IF(C5*C6=0;"";C5*C6)`
cell **C10**: `=IFS(C8="";"";C8<F3;E4;C8<G3;F4;C8<H3;G4;C8<=H3;H4;C8<=I3;I4;C8>I3;I4)`

(I changed your formulas in cells **C8** and **C10** for better)

[image]

For file **Client input file**
You must have 1st tab `clientDATA` (the more tabs do whatever you want, keep, delete makes no difference)

Client puts input in cells **C3** and **C4**
In cell **C7** you put this formula:
`=IMPORTRANGE("1HMYPA0W0gPS1A4hIo8_hWNcdhE7jQdyAKpv37Wk3m1I";"solution for client!C10")`

You also protect the tab except cells **C3** and **C4** with `Can edit (with warnings)`

[image]

**You finished**.
Now when client put numbers in cells **C3** and **C4** they see results in **C7**
**AGAIN REMEMBER: ONLY from tab `solution for client` the client will see**